# Where do I see the difference in Majorana vs. Dirac pair annihilation?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, spinors, majorana-fermions

If I have a Lagrangian density $\cal{L}=\bar{\chi}\gamma^{\mu}{\rm A}_{\mu}\chi+\bar{f}\gamma^{\mu}{\rm A} _{\mu}f$ and I calculate the diagram $\chi \bar{\chi}\to f \bar{f}$ where $f$ is (let's say) a Dirac fermion, where will I see the effect of whether $\chi$ is Majorana or Dirac?

Naively, I would calculate the $s$-channel diagram normally in either case and I can't see how the Majorana nature would manifest. When I average over the spins, I guess there would be a $\frac{1}{2} or \frac{1}{4}$ factor for Majorana or Dirac, respectively, but surely that can't be all?

If I instead calculate $\bar{\chi} \chi \to A A$, would the Majorana nature be different? Again, the only change I can foresee is the prefactor that I mentioned. My question does not concern just annihilation, so other answers concerning some decay or other process would also be useful.

Thanks in advance, and I look forward to the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi$ is Majorana, then $\bar \chi \gamma^\mu  \chi A_\mu$ is  zero, so there is no such process.

Comment: The operator is zero? Why?

Comment: Because the ${\rm U}(1)$ current $\bar \psi \gamma^\mu \psi $ changes sign when we charge conjugate $\psi\to \psi^c=C^{-1} \bar\psi^T$, and "Majorana" means that $\psi$ is its own conjugate. In other words a Majorana particle is charge neutral and cannot couple to a ${\rm U}(1)$ gauge field.

Comment: A Majorana particle can certainly couple to a U(1), there is no reason that this symmetry need to remain unbroken. In the dark photon case, for example, this happens all the time. So my question remains.

Comment: You can couple to an axial U(1) by using $\bar\psi \gamma^5 \gamma^\mu \psi$ as happens in a chiral superconductor, but in 4 d Majorana's  $\bar \psi \gamma^\mu\psi= \psi^TC \gamma^\mu \psi$ is  surely zero.....Can you give a reference for the dark-photon-Majorana coupling?

Comment: I see, this axial-vector current is actually what I am seeing in the literature. In here, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01730.pdf, and other similar papers, you see that they do exactly what you suggest. But why can't I have a vector coupling? If my U(1) is spontaneously broken, then I shouldn't be worrying about my Lagrangian being invariant under the symmetry, no?

Comment: That the vector current opertor  $\bar \psi \gamma^\mu\psi$ is identically zero for Majorana fermions is a algebraic property of the  Majorana fermion field. It is basically that the anticommutation relations make $\psi^T M \psi=0$ when $M$ is symmetric. This  can't be altered by anything tha gauge or any other field does.

Comment: Okay, I mostly understand the solution. But based on your answer, how can I have a neutrino NC interaction, for example? If neutrinos are majorana, then shouldn't this operator not be included?